# SignalR not working for specific ID

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I'm using SignalR and MVC to push notifications out to the user while they're on the site. It works as long as I send the notification to all of them, but when I try to isolate the user I get nothing. No error thrown on either side, it just silently fails.

This is my Hub code:

```
public class NotificationHub : Hub
{
    private readonly static IDictionary<int, string> _connections = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    public static void AddNotification(int userId, Notification notification)
    {
        if (notification != null)
        {
            string userConnectionId = null;

            _connections.TryGetValue(userId, out userConnectionId);

            //Send message only if the user is currently connected.
            if (userConnectionId != null)
            {
                IHubContext hub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();

                hub.Clients.Client(userConnectionId)
                    .addNotification(
                        notification.ID, 
                        notification.ShowMessage(), 
                        notification.Link);
            }
        }
    }

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        if(_connections.ContainsKey(WebSecurity.CurrentUserId))
        {
            _connections[WebSecurity.CurrentUserId] = Context.ConnectionId;
        }
        else
        {
            _connections.Add(WebSecurity.CurrentUserId, Context.ConnectionId);
        }

        return base.OnConnected();
    }
}
```

This is my JS code:

```
var notificationConnection = $.connection.notificationHub;

notificationConnection.client.addNotification = function (id, message, link) {
    alert(message);
};

$.connection.hub.start().done(function () { });
```

There seems to be something wrong with the connection ID, but I've somewhat followed the example on the SignalR page: https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections

**Edit:**

Just to clarify. If I replace:

```
hub.Clients.Client(userConnectionId)
    .addNotification(
        notification.ID, 
        notification.ShowMessage(), 
        notification.Link);
```

with:

```
hub.Clients.All
    .addNotification(
        notification.ID, 
        notification.ShowMessage(), 
        notification.Link);
```

it works.

So the problem seems to be with this line: `hub.Clients.Client(userConnectionId)`

And I've also made sure the userConnectionId is populated when the function runs, and it is.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently getting an instance of the Hub from within the hub itself, this is not necessary and will likely lead to unexpected behavior:

```
IHubContext hub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();

hub.Clients.Client(userConnectionId)
                .addNotification(
                    notification.ID, 
                    notification.ShowMessage(), 
                    notification.Link);
```

... can be changed to ...

```
this.Clients.Client(userConnectionId)
                .addNotification(
                    notification.ID, 
                    notification.ShowMessage(), 
                    notification.Link);
```

Also, your code will fail silently, because when the `TryGetValue()` comes back as `null`, it won't even attempt to send the notification.  There is no error that is occurring specifically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Luke. The `AddNotification` function is actually static, so it's called outside of the Hub instance. And I've checked that the `TryGetValue()` actually passes, and it does. The failing is inside the `Client()` function. If I replace `Client()` with `All` I get the notification I want.